# Call Masonry JS on Class Instead of Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, masonry

I have some javascript code that is currently called on a div with the id of "lesson."  I'd like to call it on a class instead since I have more than one div to call it on. It's for a rails application.

Here's the js:

```
$(function() {
  return $('#lesson').imagesLoaded(function() {
    return $('#lesson').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      isFitWidth: true
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks for any suggestions!